# Add numbers to the end of a decimal point (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem. I need to get two numbers and add them together in a way that one is the decimal point of the other. For example:

```
double number1 = 20;
double number2 = 142;
```

I need to add these numbers together to get 20.142. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
bool negative = (number1 < 0.0);

if (negative)
    number1 = 0 - number1;
while (number2 >= 1.0)
    number2 = number2 / 10.0;

double finalnum = number1 + number2;
if (negative)
    finalnum = 0 - finalnum;
```

It's quite simple. We first determine if `number1` is negative, and if so, make it positive and set a boolean flag. Then we just keep dividing `number2` by `10.0` until it is less than `1.0` (which means it's now on the range `[0, 1)` assuming it's positive). Then we just add the two numbers together and store it in `finalnum`, and if `negative` is `true` (`YES`), negate `finalnum`.

This solution could have also been solved using base-10 logarithms to determine the amount to divide `number2` by, but that most likely will take longer.

You could also have solved this by [turning those numbers into `const char*` or `CFString` (Objective-C) strings and then concatenate them followed by an interpretation of the resulting string as a `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10368864/1350209), but again, this will take longer.

There are two caveats to this code:

1. `number1` and `number2` must be integers (if `number1` was, say, `1.5` and `number2` was `25.7`, `finalnum` would be `1.757`)
2. `number2` must be positive

Answer (score 5):

Simplistic solution:

```
double result = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.%i", (int)number1, (int)number2] doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use *math.* (Dun dun DUNNNNNNN!)

```
double number3 = number1 + (number2 / 1000);
```

So the problem becomes; how do you determine the power of 10 by which to divide your second number?

There's surely many ways to do this.  Just off the top of my head, you can run a loop which continuously increases the power of ten until it's greater-than the current value of number2.

If you're dealing with a negative number for number1, then you'll want to add an **if** statement to see if the number is < 0.  If so, you'll want to subtract instead of add.

If you're dealing with a negative number for number2, well... that's just silly.

Comment: math.ceil(log10(number2)) should help with the question you posed.

Answer (score 2):

A naive way:

```
double res, number1 = 20, number2 = 142;
while (number2 >= 1) {
    number2 /= 10;
}
res = number1 + number2;
```

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Do you want me to give you the expected answer if 142 was negative?

Comment: @CoreCode - No, what would you expect as a result if number2 was -142?

Comment: You may want to edit your question to specify that you're dealing with negative numbers as well, and post what the expected output would be if number2 is negative.  It sort of makes sense for number1, but since number2 is just being appended to the end of the decimal place, it makes no sense.

Comment: If the second number was negative, it would have to carry thought to the first number. e.g. if it was 20 and -142 then the number would be -20.142